# Create countdown timer relative to current real time?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to workout how to create a countdown that displays the current time remaining in a day shown below is the layout, so there's 3 TextViews IDs would be days, hours, minutes

[image]

how can I get the current remaining time and display them in the textview? but also allow for a timer start time at an arbitrary time of day, so the 24 hour starting period could be from midnight, so the timer elapsed time at 10am would show 14 hours left, or the 24 hour period starts from 6am so the timer for 10am would show 18 hours left.

would it be easier to just have it start from midnight and then somehow add 3 hours in the code, if anyone knows how to do all this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int timeinminutes = 1;

    sSlUp = findViewById(R.id.redtimeerview);
    //final TextView hours = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hours);

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeinminutes * 60000, 1000) {
        TextView countdownText = findViewById(R.id.countdown_text);
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long scnds = 1;
            scnds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            countdownText.setText("" + scnds);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    }.start();


    init();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.previewCam);
    mBtLaunchActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_launch_activity);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentDate);
    setDate(textView);

    mBtLaunchActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            launchActivity();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey Marc. Start by reading the `Time` package documentation. [here it is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). By the way the question is hard to read. You may want to rewrite it a bit.

Comment: tried to tidy it up if it makes a bit more sense now?

Comment: It does. Can you provide some of the code you have to have something to start from?

Comment: added some code to where I think ill need to add it if that helps. I guess somewhere after the countdowntimer. I know how to display the current time no problem, but I need to get time remaining is where im failing to figure out what to do

I have searched, but a lot of results seem to be days/time remaining to a set date (like Christmas or an event)

Answer (score 1):

As per requested here is an attempt. Please not that this answer has not been tested.

All data not relevant of the `Time` has been removed.

```
int timeInMinutes = 1;

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeInMinutes * 60000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Time time = new Time(millisUntilFinished);

            final int hours = time.getHours();
            final int min = time.getMinutes();
            final int scnds = time.getSeconds();

            countdownText.setText("" + scnds);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // Everytime the countDown stops restart it?
            //countDownTimer.start();
        }
    }.start();
```

Relevant link:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html

Answer (score 0):

oh thanks!! that I believe put me on the right track, while it wasn't apparently correct as the .getHours and .getMinutes apparently is depreciated since api 14. I saw that I could us a compare to and then set that against the time

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int timeinminutes = 1;

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeinminutes * 60000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Time time = new Time(millisUntilFinished);

            final int hours = time.compareTo(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); //added a compareto and set that against what the current time is
            final int min = time.getMinutes();
            //final int scnds = time.getSeconds();
            long scnds = 1;
            scnds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            countdownText.setText("" + scnds);
            countdownHours.setText("" +hours); // sets to ID of textview
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    }.start();
```

when I tested this it says 1 hour (current time is 22:54) so im sure its correct but id have to check tomorrow. but thanks for pointing me in the right direction :D all I need to do now is work out how to offset the hours so currently it should say 4 hours

thanks very much

Comment: glad I could help you out. Sorry for pointing you to a deprecated API, my java is a tidy bit dating :P

Answer (score 0):

After searching alot from internet i can't get any built in function for this. Maybe there is any function but for me i use to do code like this and it really worked for me. Just copy paste it and set timerTV according to yours text View.

```
  var cT: CountDownTimer? = null

  fun timer() {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time
    Log.d("Current time: ", calendar.time.toString())

    val hourCurrent = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)
    val minutCurrent = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
    val secondCurrent = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)
    
    var hourSub = 24 - hourCurrent
    var minSub = 60 - minutCurrent
    var secSub = 60 - secondCurrent


    cT = object : CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            timerTV.setText("$hourSub:$minSub:$secSub")

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            timer()
        }
    }
    cT?.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    cT?.cancel()
}
```